# unable to open a file in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My requirement is to open the pdf file in the webpage. Below code is used to display the pdf file in the browsers(chrome and IE).
But the **issue is with IE**, before the pdf file is getting opened an alert box which says Access is denied is being displayed. Please suggest how to open the pdf file in the internet explorer by using the below code
without displaying an alert box(Access is denied).html code:

```
<div ng-controller="myPDFFileController">
<object ng-if="!IEBrowser" data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 1200px;overflow-y: hidden; cursor:pointer;"></object> 
<iframe ng-if="IEBrowser" id ="pdfIframe" ></iframe>
</div>
```

js code:

```
app.controller('myPDFFileController', function ($scope,MyAppService) {
      $scope.getPDFPathFileName  = function () {
             MyAppService.getPDFPathFileName().then(
            function (response) {
                if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                   $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                    $scope.content = response;
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.content = response;
                        document.querySelector('#pdfIframe').setAttribute('src',$scope.content);
                    }, 0);
                } else {

                    $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                    $scope.content = response;
                }
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
            });
     }
      $scope.getPDFPathFileName();
});
```

--EDITED--

//service call

```
    myAppService.getPDFPathFileName= function(){
    //logic
    var Url = myURL+'/getFiles/getPDF.form';
     ̲$http.get(repUrl).then(
    function (response) {
       deferred.resolve(response.data);}
    ̶function(errResponse){
        deferred.reject(errResponse);
        });
return deferred.promise;
    }
```

response in the js controller is /resources/myfiles/abc.pdf

Comment: Tr changing $scope.content=response.data. What value is there inside response and show the code for MyAppService?

Comment: @Vivz - Please see my edited post above. I think its not with the response, as the response which is the path and the filename I got is correct and even chrome and IE is displaying the PDF. Issue is in the IE before the pdf is loaded in the webpage an alert box with message Access is denied is displayed and then the pdf is loaded.

Comment: You are opening this pdf with which software?

Comment: I am using pdfObject.js.

Comment: When you try to save a PDF file from a website, you get the error “access denied” on adobe. That I know how to solve

Comment: @Vivz - Can u please read my question. I am facing issue in IE when I'm trying to load the pdf file and show in the webpage. I can able to load the pdf file successfully and show in chrome and even in IE, but issue is in IE Access denied alert is showing before the pdf is loaded.

Comment: Read this http://www.fixkb.com/2012/07/access-denied-when-opening-a-pdf.html and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/access-denied-windows-7-internet-explorer-9-cant/bde2361c-40d3-41c6-9153-dc02cd7dcb4e